# How do I return the content of a element onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to this and hoping someone can help me with the syntax for returning the contents of element when clicking on the element.

How to I get the alert to say "return this value"?

```js
function getValue(elem) {
  var thisValue = elem.value; //need help with this bit please
  alert(thisValue);
};
```

```html
<h3 onclick="getValue(this)">return this value</h3>
```

Comment: The code **doesn't  `return`** from the function it only shows the text. And usually you don't return from event listeners

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your element is `h3` use `innerHTML` insted of `value`

```js
function getValue(elem) {
            var thisValue = elem.innerHTML; 
            alert(thisValue);
 };
```

```html
<h3 onclick="getValue(this)">return this value</h3>
```

`value` is normally used for `input` elements. `innerHTML` is normally used for `div, span, td , h1-h6` and similar elements.

Answer (score 1):

- textContent -> only the text, for example `"Foobar"`
- innerHTML -> every nested piece of html, for example `"<h3><div>Foobar</div></h3>"`

```js
 function getValue(elem) {
            var thisValue = elem.textContent;  //need help with this bit please
            alert(thisValue);
 };
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Answer (score 0):

the answer from @manikant gautam is good, but if you need the text only from the element, then you can also try the following code:

```
 function getValue(elem) {
        //it will show you only the pure and clean text of the element 
        var thisValue = elem.innerText; 
        alert(thisValue);
        }

        <h3 onclick="getValue(this)">return this value</h3>
```

Hope it will work for you...